# SharePoint Online - Modified by not consistent

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am trying to get to the bottom of how SharePoint Online manages the modified by field for folders. When created a folder has a modified by set - great that's correct. If someone add files to that folder on few instance it will say that folder has been modified by that person and sometimes not.

Any ideas whats causing this randomness? Does it depend on if the folder is accessed through windows explorer or accessed via the web interface? Either way its very confusing.
Thanks